# How to require XML element with specific value of attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I validate that an element has specific attribute and attribute must have specific value.

For example:

```
<macroField dictTag="referenceNum">a2398</macroField>
```

I need to validate that my XML contains element name macroField with attribute dictTag="referenceNum" and also the value of this tag is a string.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'validate'? Just an XSD describing the constraints or an application enforcing them during runtime?

Comment: I mean how to defile complexType for element like this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<xs:element name="macroField">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="dictTag" type="xs:string" fixed="referenceNum"/>     
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I think that's what I've been looking for! the 'fixed' keyword. I was going to use enumeration but with only one possible value enumeration did not make much sense. I'll run a simple test, if ok, I'll accept this answer. Thanks.